Why does SetN.contains not allow null arguments?
Line in reference: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ec0618742ff6cfd6d83f1278e8d245673fb9ef2c/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ImmutableCollections.java#L946
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(o);           <- Why is this here?
        return size > 0 && probe(o) >= 0;
    }

This means one cannot accept any Set object (that they have no control over) and simply use .contains(null) to check whether the set contains a null value. There are Sets that can contain null values, so this is a legitimate check.

"Why" questions like this are not good questions. Please describe what you expect as an answer.

"There are Sets that can contain null values, so this is a legitimate check." yes, and those sets have their own implementation of contains. For example HashSet doesn't have that check.

Either it throws the exception at the start of the contains method, or it throws the exception in the probe method. Where it calls pk.hashCode(). If you really want to know then you could use set#stream#anyMatch.

@Sweeper I expect an answer that answers the question, like the one I accepted

@Alan technically they didn't answer the question you've asked. There is no "why they did this" Your question is probably better stated as "Is this set implementation broken because one cannot simply use .contains(null) to check for a null value? Then the answer answers pretty clearly. "No it is not broken, it is a part of the API .contains(null) does not work on all sets."

@matt I agree that is a good alternative question to ask, and a preferred one for this site.
Regarding your other points,

I believe "Why did a person do this?" is a legitimate/valid question for anything a person does.
I believe the accepted answer does answer the question. Why questions can have layer-1 answers, layer-2 answers (the answer to 'Why layer-1?'), etc. The accepted answer is a layer-2 answer, in my opinion. It gives more information than a direct answer to the alternative question.


I agree there are some merit's to "why" questions. I think in the context of this site their discouraged on principle because more often than not they can be improved.  The discussion on the meta goes over it pretty well.

If you have a method that takes a Set as an argument and calls contains(null), it is already broken and has been since Java 1.4, when the behaviour of Set.contains was changed to specify that it may throw NullPointerException.
Compare 1.3 with 1.4:
https://javaalmanac.io/jdk/1.3/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)
https://javaalmanac.io/jdk/1.4/api/java/util/Set.html#contains(java.lang.Object)
In 1.4, this line was added:

NullPointerException - if the specified element is null and this set does not support null elements (optional).

Therefore, ever since Java 1.4 (more than 20 years ago), any method that calls Set.contains(null) should be prepared for it to throw NPE, unless that method explicitly specifies that it only accepts Sets that allow nulls.
It could be argued that this broke backward compatibility between 1.3 and 1.4, but given how old 1.4 is, this is of only historical significance.

Thanks for the answer. I see this is documented all the way up to Collection: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Collection.java#L289

Because SetN does not allow null elements. This is not a public class and as such is not documented, but this can be inferred from the docs of Set. The section about unmodifiable sets returned from Set.of() and Set.copyOf(), explicitly state that they do not allow nulls (SetN is one of the implementations used by the overloads of these methods):

They disallow null elements. Attempts to create them with null elements result in NullPointerException.

At the same time the docs of Set.contains(Object) state that the method throws NPE, if the element is null and the set does not permit nulls:

NullPointerException - if the specified element is null and this set does not permit null elements

This implementation of SetN.contains() is to be expected considering the documentation.
